# Find value in table for ISOWEEKNUM - excel

Tags: excel, sum, week-number

I want to write  sum for value for specific weeknum.
I solve preblem for mouth with code.

> = SUMIFS('Izredni dogodek - Č'!$Q:$Q;'Izredni dogodek -
> Č'!$D:$D;">="&$B13;'Izredni dogodek -
> Č'!$D:$D;"<="&EOMONTH($B13;0);'Izredni dogodek - Č'!$C:$C;"Mletje
> rude")

THE MAIN DATABASE:

[image]

I will need the code for weeknum: the picture down.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you could provide some sample data in english. What is your Excel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to get the value per calendar week:

Formula in E2: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11)*(ISOWEEKNUM($A$2:$A$11)=D2))`

[image]